# How can I disable `Initializing JS/TS Language Features` when using Python extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get an annoying, **constantly** running "*Initializing JS/TS language features*" message on the status bar of Visual Studio Code (latest version, Windows 10), and in the Notifications area.  I have the main Python plugin extension installed (and **no** JS/Typescript plugin installed). There are several duplicate bug reports on github about this, but afaik they are all marked as closed/resolved. (There is also another stackOverflow question on this, but it is about the JavaScript plugin and marked as "answered.")

Thank you.

(--fwiw, the "experts Exchange" advises reinstalling Windows, which seems a bit disproportionate:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29164123/Powershell-Initializing-JS-TS-language-features-stuck-on-the-status-bar-VSCode.html
)

Comment: When does this Initializing happen? during a build/debug launch?

Comment: The initializing is *always* happening, with some code open, with no code open -- regardless of what I do.  I haven't figured out *any* way to make it stop.

Comment: Note for people with related issues on how to debug/find extension problems: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want those features, you can disable the builtin Feature provider in VSCode

Open Extensions panel (CTRL+SHIFT+X)

`Show Built-in extensions`

Find `Typescript and Javascript language features` in the Features panel

Disable the extension (preferably just for your python workspace)

[image: Disable built in extension]

Comment: Thank you tHeSiD, disabling the built-in TypeScript/JavaScript extension from the workplace solved the problem. (I hadn't noticed the location of it before.)

Comment: Hah! Thats why I have 4 portable VSCode instances minutely customized for various language configurations! :D

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out that I had a addon for visual studio that caused the problem.

What I had to do was basically to disable all my addons and then enable a few more then try visual studio, if it still worked enable a few more until you found the guilty one.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the VS Code Extension: Teams Toolkit

Uninstalling the Teams Tooklit extension removed the "Initializing JS/TS language features" message on the status bar every other second.